# SPICE protocol extension

Tags: kvm

I am doing a project that extends SPICE. I need to send some custom data between server and client. I beleiev this is done by adding a custom channel to the SPICE protocol

I've got the source code, but it's huge and overwhelming. Can anyone give me a few pointers as to how to start, or direct me to a similar project so I can refer?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to start reading the "SPICE for Newbies" document, then moving to other documentation. It will give you some introduction on the architecture of SPICE, the protocol, standard channels, etc.

Available on [spice-space.org/documentation.html](http://spice-space.org/documentation.html)

Answer (score 1):

Since spice-gtk 0.15, and qemu 1.4.0, you can set up arbitrary channels by name using the "Spice port", see spicy.c code for an example of usage.